# best method to implement a sliding window for selective repeat protocol in c

Tags: networking, udp, send

I am rather new to networking and I was looking into how I should implement a sliding window for the selective repeat protocol. My initial idea was to use a linked list in order to resend the unacknowledged frames (I would insert it into the correct place) and use the window as a sort of priority queue. I am able to send frames between the sender and receiver but I don't know where to begin with to implement a sliding window. I was wondering if I could get any tips as to how to implement a sliding window.